# Checkbox 'change' event  works when click the label . in ie8, ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my form I have a `CheckBox`, and I have a label to CheckBox. In firefox & IE9, the CheckBox `change event` works as expected ,but in IE8 & IE7 , the event fires when click the label but not the checkbox.

**My HTML**

```
<div class="item-container">
    <div class="label-container">
    </div>
    <div class="textbox-container">
        <input id="AddNewProductCategory" class="" type="checkbox" width="20px" height="20px"
            value="1" name="addnewproductcategory" tabindex="1900" />
    </div>
    <div class="after-checkbox-label">
        <label class="Verdana11-424039" for="AddNewProductCategory">
            Add New Service Category</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My jQuery**

```
jq('#AddNewProductCategory').change(function(){
    jq('#CategoryName').next('label[for=CategoryName]').remove();
    jq('#Category').next('label[for=Category]').remove();

    if (!jq('#AddNewProductCategory').is(':checked')) {
         alert("in change");
        jq('input[name="newcategory"]').val('');
        jq('#CategoryName').hide();     
        jq('#store_category').hide();
        jq('#Category').removeAttr('disabled');

    }
    else {
        jq('#Category').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        jq('#CategoryName').show();     
        jq('#store_category').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: what version of jquery do you have ?

Comment: According to this document http://api.jquery.com/change/:
"As of jQuery 1.4, the change event bubbles in Internet Explorer, behaving consistently with the event in other modern browsers."

Consider changing jquery version.

Comment: let us know if it helped

Comment: hmmm........... i changed the 'change' event to 'click' event and now it works , thanks guys

Comment: Just a tip - don't paste the code here, add it on jsfiddle and give us the link. Live examples are better.

Answer (score 8):

Just for future references, from what I remember, the "change" event is a bit buggy in older versions of IE.

You have to use the `propertychange` event in IE to get it to behave as expected. The code I like to use is:

**Edit 2 (back to the core)**

```
$(element).on(navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i) ? "propertychange" : "change", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Your code here
});
```

**Edit 1 (buggy, not reliable)**

```
$(element).on(!$.support.changeBubbles ? "propertychange" : "change", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Your code here
});
```

This code has been updated to work with jQuery 1.9+ with some input from Marius in the comments.

**Original (deprecated)**

Here is the old code for those using the older versions of jQ:

```
$(element).bind($.browser.msie ? 'propertychange' : 'change', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: For those that still have to support IE8, even in 2013, I found that this issue does not occur in IE9 and above. So I used `($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9)` for my check.

Comment: $.browser is now deprecated in jquery 1.9+. You can replace that with if (!$.support.changeBubbles).

Comment: Thanks Marius, I've been looking for an update for that line of code - the best I have is (for the simplicity) `/msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())`.