# jQuery append only visible after second append in IE8

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

Can't seem to find any good answers with this issue. Hoping someone can help

Details: Each time the user selects an item from a dropdown, I append some stuff to a div above. This can happen as many times as the user wants.

Issue: In IE8 only, The append only appends every other time, including the previous selection. No errors or anything. This works perfectly fine in any other browser. Viewing the DOM, i can see the html is added, but it doesnt show up on the page until i click another item in the dropdown.

For example: You select the first item from the dropdown, you will not see anything, but if you select something else from the dropdown, both of you selections show up at once.

```
$("#ddCurriculumSelectList").change(function (e) {


    $("#selectedCurricPlaceholder").append('<div class="curriculumLine" ><div class="grid-10-12"><label>' + $("#ddCurriculumSelectList option:selected").text() + '</label><input type="hidden" class="selCurricField" id="selectedCurriculum' + $("#ddCurriculumSelectList option:selected").val() + '" name="SelectedCurriculum" value="' + $("#ddCurriculumSelectList option:selected").val() + '" /></div><div class="grid-2-12"><a href="#" class="removeCurriculum" style="padding-left: 10px;"><img src="Images/webicon/minus16.png" /></a></div></div>');


});
```

As far as i can tell, the HTML i append is correct and has no missing closing tags or anything

Any Ideas?

**EDIT 1:** 
Adding a fiddle. Since its for IE8 i'll include an embedded version

Fiddle Result: http://jsfiddle.net/mungoid/Ge3cz/11/

Full Screen Result: http://jsfiddle.net/mungoid/Ge3cz/11/embedded/result/

**EDIT 2:**
Oooh, i think its because once i remove the item from the dropdown after adding it to the div, it has to change the selected option, which causes the event to fire again. Sorry i didnt include that in my original code. I didnt think that was the cause and cut it =-/

Still not sure how to handle that though

**EDIT 3:** 
.. Geez, Scratch that previous edit 2. I thought it was cause of the remove line but it still does it without removing the selected option

Comment: From my experience with older versions of Incompetent Explorer, they have a problem detecting the change event. There is a bit of code I like to use which gets around this issue gracefully by using the change event while providing an alternative for IE. This can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005442/checkbox-change-event-works-when-click-the-label-in-ie8-ie7/8926190#8926190

Comment: So yep that did help and now the event fires in IE8! Thanks for that link. However, it is now being called multiple times? Sometimes 3 times, sometimes 2 times. Its weird cause it does not get fired multiple times in other browsers. And i checked and double checked that i dont have multiple events tied to this. Ideas?

Comment: Can you post your complete mark-up here please? Or create a jsfiddle with it. Or both.

Comment: Added links to the full fiddle and the one that works for IE8. As you will be able to see, it adds only one in all other browsers but not for IE8. Havent tested in lower browsers because 8 is the min we are supporting. Hopefully its not something stupid i did thats breaking it

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/SWfVL/